# How do I fix unix so that I can use the cursor on the shell?

Tags: unix, shell

I was able to use the up/dow arrow to cycle through previous commands, now when I press a directional key it outputs "^[[A". I'm running on a bash shell. How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of termcaps. See you next year.

Answer (score 0):

Try to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and redo it.